# Which part of the Certificate Signing Request is hashed before signing?

Tags: certificate, verification, csr

I quite understand the part that after creating a CSR it is sent to the CA where it is signed with its private key. Now I want to create an algorithm that would do a backward check of authenticity from "pubcert>issuing ca>to subroot ca> to root ca" by verifying the signatures in its certificates and the public key of the CA that signed it. The problem is I don't know what is the input needed to do verification. See to initiate verification i have to do like "C_Verify(session handle, public key, input, inputLength, signature, signature length)". In my case, signature and signature length is from the pubcert while the public key would be from the issuing CA but I do not know what the input part would be?

Comment: Certificate requests aren’t signed by CAs, they read the request, copy out whatever parts they want (but definitely the public key), add whatever they want, then sign that. You want to read [RFC 5280](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280), which explains the whole chaining algorithm and signature aspects.

Comment: @bartonjs Thank you for replying to my question.  After a certificate request is signed a public certificate is generated, the public certificate should contain a signature. I needed to know which part of the pub certificate (which part of the memory map specifically) was signed to generate that signature.

Comment: yep, RFC 5280 will explain that (tbsCertificate).

Comment: @bartonjs ow thank you so much. Found it!

Comment: apparently byte[06] and byte[07] from the certificates memory map points out the length of the data to be signed -  from byte[04] to whatever length byte[06] byte[07] translate to. << just leaving this out here just in case someone needs it